# xCode, storing data on the device and up loading to a server database later

Tags: database, xcode, server, storing-data

does anyone know of a tutorial that covers the following:

My App has a number of questions put to the user. Is there a way to store the anwsers on the device in a database, and when all the questions have been anwsered upload the results to the database server.

Any advice or tutorials on this subject would be great.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NSUserDefaults, CoreData, or Realm DB as options to store on the device. Here is a tutorial on how to use Realm DB: https://www.raywenderlich.com/112544/realm-tutorial-getting-started

Im not sure what backend you are using to host the DB but here is a tutorial on how to use firebase https://www.raywenderlich.com/109706/firebase-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Hi Steve, many thanks for your reply. I have some reading to do.